# Why does Go use "tophash[0]" to represent this bucket has been evacuated?

Tags: dictionary, go

Why does `func evacuated` in golang source code [src/runtime/map.go](https://go.dev/src/runtime/map.go) use `tophash[0]` to represent that this bucket has been evacuated?

```
func evacuated(b *bmap) bool {
    h := b.tophash[0]
    return h > emptyOne && h < minTopHash
}
```

Doesn't `tophash[0]` just represent the first cell in the bucket?
How can Go determine that the entire bucket has been migrated using just the first element of tophash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tophash` is a bmap type. The bmap type definition contains a partial explanation.

```
// A bucket for a Go map.

type bmap struct {
    // tophash generally contains the top byte of the hash value
    // for each key in this bucket. If tophash[0] < minTopHash,
    // tophash[0] is a bucket evacuation state instead.
    tophash [bucketCnt]uint8
    // Followed by bucketCnt keys and then bucketCnt elems.
    // NOTE: packing all the keys together and then all the elems together makes the
    // code a bit more complicated than alternating key/elem/key/elem/... but it allows
    // us to eliminate padding which would be needed for, e.g., map[int64]int8.
    // Followed by an overflow pointer.
}
```

> If tophash[0] < minTopHash, tophash[0] is a bucket evacuation state instead.

The `tophash[i]` value is overloaded. Normally it contains the top byte of the hash value of the ith entry, but if it's less than `minTopHash` it's not a hash value but one of the above special flags indicating its evacuation state.

`minTopHash` is defined earlier in the file and provides the second piece of the puzzle.

```
    // Possible tophash values. We reserve a few possibilities for special marks.
    // Each bucket (including its overflow buckets, if any) will have either all or none of its
    // entries in the evacuated* states (except during the evacuate() method, which only happens
    // during map writes and thus no one else can observe the map during that time).
    emptyRest      = 0 // this cell is empty, and there are no more non-empty cells at higher indexes or overflows.
    emptyOne       = 1 // this cell is empty
    evacuatedX     = 2 // key/elem is valid.  Entry has been evacuated to first half of larger table.
    evacuatedY     = 3 // same as above, but evacuated to second half of larger table.
    evacuatedEmpty = 4 // cell is empty, bucket is evacuated.
    minTopHash     = 5 // minimum tophash for a normal filled cell.
```

> Each bucket (including its overflow buckets, if any) will have either all or none of its entries in the evacuated* states

If one bucket entry is being evacuated, they're all being evacuated, so it only has to look at one `tophash` entry. It uses `tophash[0]`, but if the comment is to be believed it could use `tophash[3]` or `tophash[6]`.

Note: I don't have any special knowledge about the code, I'm just reading what's there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice the bmap comment in the source code!

Comment: There is another question.

I understand that tophash[0] < minTopHash indicates evacuation progress of the entire bucket. For example, tophash[0] = evacuatedX indicates that the entire bucket has been evacuated.

Compared with tophash[0], tophash[1-7] is different in that they can set their own state to represent the migration state of data in their own cell. For example, tophash[2] = evacuatedX, indicating that data evacuatedx in the cell cell2 has been migrated.

The question is: tophash[0] this 0 cell, its own data state is represented by what?

Comment: @AlexShang The comment says "*Each bucket (including its overflow buckets, if any) will have either all or none of its entries in the evacuated* states*". I understand that to mean `tophash[0]` is its own state. It's not that `tophash[0]` stores the bucket evacuation state, but that the bucket evacuation state can be derived by looking at `tophash[0]`. I think `evacuated` would work if it looked at any entry in `tophash`. It would be interesting to try. Note: I'm just reading the code, I don't have any special knowledge of this.